# How to control arduino by a pc with c++

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to control my arduino board by my own c++ or java programme. Basically I want to get values from arduino. And perform some tasks based on that values. Simply,I have connected a potentiometer to arduino and I want to read its value in my programme.

Comment: This question is overly broad. There's nothing we can really help you with here.

Comment: Your best bet is to use python with pyserial library.

Comment: Check out processing: https://processing.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the telecommand to control the arduino from your pc. pc will send a string, and a program for the control of the input string on arduino

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad so its difficult to give a direct answer, but the normal way is to use serial coms via a USB cable. In your Arduino code use either Serial or SoftwareSerial to open a connection. In your C++ application you will open a connection to the same COM port your Arduino is connected to.

There is some example code on the Arduino website:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

It's then up to you to decide on a protocol for passing data back and forth. This depends entirely on your needs, so we can't really help you unless you give more information.